# Javascript files in "feature folders/slices" Aspnet Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to adapt the feature folders/slices for my aspnet core MVC app.

I have managed to server controller and cshtml files from the features folder.

[image]

With this code...

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyApp.Web
{
    public class FeatureFolderViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
    {
        public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
        {
            /* no-op */
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
        {
            // {0} - Action Name
            // {1} - Controller Name
            // {2} - Area name

            object area;
            if (context.ActionContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("area", out area))
            {
                yield return "/Areas/{2}/{1}/{0}.cshtml";
                yield return "/Areas/{2}/Shared/{0}.cshtml";
                yield return "/Areas/Shared/{0}.cshtml";
            }
            else
            {
                yield return "/Features/{1}/{0}.cshtml";
                yield return "/Features/Shared/{0}.cshtml";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and..

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new FeatureFolderViewLocationExpander());
    });
}
```

... but I have not managed to server the .js files from the features folder (eg. home.js in my solution above).

Is is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the static files outside of web root , you could configure the Static File Middleware as follows :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...

        app.UseStaticFiles();//For the wwwroot folder

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Features")),
            RequestPath = "/Features"
        });

        ...
    }
```

Then access it with the below path

```
<script src="~/Features/Home/home.js"></script>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: You sir - are the best! Thanks!